# Collision-detection for an SDL game

Tags: c++, game, collision, sdl

I am working on a simple SDL game in C++. I want to make my collision detection implementation better.

Here's the complete project:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 512;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 512;

bool initialize_game();
bool load_game();
void close_game();
SDL_Texture* load_texture(std::string path);

bool check_collision(SDL_Rect a, SDL_Rect b);

SDL_Texture* playerOneTexture = NULL;
SDL_Window* globalWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* globalRenderer = NULL;

class Timer
{
    public:
        Timer();

        void start_timer();
        void stop_timer();
        bool is_started();

        Uint32 get_ticks();

    private:
        Uint32 startTicks;
        Uint32 pausedTicks;

        bool isPaused;
        bool isStarted;
};

class Player
{
    public:
        const int PLAYER_WIDTH = 32;
        const int PLAYER_HEIGHT = 32;
        const int PLAYER_VELOCITY = 160;

        Player();

        void move_player(float timeStep, SDL_Rect objectWeHit);
        void render_player(float positionX, float positionY, SDL_Texture* texture, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL, double angle = 0.0, SDL_Point* center = NULL, SDL_RendererFlip flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE);
        void handle_player_event(SDL_Event &event);

        float positionX, positionY;
        float velocityX, velocityY;

    private:
        SDL_Rect playerCollider;
};

Timer::Timer()
{
    startTicks = 0;
    pausedTicks = 0;

    isPaused = false;
    isStarted = false;
}

void Timer::start_timer()
{
    isStarted = true;
    isPaused = false;

    startTicks = SDL_GetTicks();
    pausedTicks = 0;
}

void Timer::stop_timer()
{
    isStarted = false;
    isPaused = false;

    startTicks = 0;
    pausedTicks = 0;
}

Uint32 Timer::get_ticks()
{
    Uint32 time = 0;

    if(isStarted){
        time = SDL_GetTicks() - startTicks;
    }
    return time;
}

bool Timer::is_started()
{
    return isStarted;
}

Player::Player()
{
    positionX = 0.0;
    positionY = 0.0;

    velocityX = 0.0;
    velocityY = 0.0;

    playerCollider.w = PLAYER_WIDTH;
    playerCollider.h = PLAYER_HEIGHT;
}

void Player::move_player(float timeStep, SDL_Rect objectWeHit)
{
    positionX += velocityX * timeStep;
    playerCollider.x = positionX;

    if(positionX < 0){
        positionX = 0;
        playerCollider.x = positionX;
    }
    if(positionX > SCREEN_WIDTH - PLAYER_WIDTH){
        positionX = SCREEN_WIDTH - PLAYER_WIDTH;
        playerCollider.x = positionX;
    }

    positionY += velocityY * timeStep;
    playerCollider.y = positionY;

    if(positionY < 0){
        positionY = 0;
        playerCollider.y = positionY;
    }
    if(positionY > SCREEN_HEIGHT - PLAYER_HEIGHT){
        positionY = SCREEN_HEIGHT - PLAYER_HEIGHT;
        playerCollider.y = positionY;
    }

    if(check_collision(playerCollider, objectWeHit)){
        positionX -= (velocityX * timeStep);
        positionY -= (velocityY * timeStep);
        playerCollider.x = positionX;
        playerCollider.y = positionY;
    }
}

void Player::render_player(float positionX, float positionY, SDL_Texture* texture, SDL_Rect* clip, double angle, SDL_Point* center, SDL_RendererFlip flip)
{
    SDL_Rect renderQuad = { positionX, positionY, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT };

    if( clip != NULL )
    {
        renderQuad.w = clip->w;
        renderQuad.h = clip->h;
    }

    SDL_RenderCopyEx(globalRenderer, texture, clip, &renderQuad, angle, center, flip );
}

void Player::handle_player_event(SDL_Event &event)
{
    if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.repeat == 0){
        switch(event.key.keysym.sym){
            case SDLK_UP:
            velocityY -= PLAYER_VELOCITY;
            break;

            case SDLK_DOWN:
            velocityY += PLAYER_VELOCITY;
            break;

            case SDLK_LEFT:
            velocityX -= PLAYER_VELOCITY;
            break;

            case SDLK_RIGHT:
            velocityX += PLAYER_VELOCITY;
            break;
        }
    }
    else if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.repeat == 0){
        switch(event.key.keysym.sym){
            case SDLK_UP:
            velocityY += PLAYER_VELOCITY;
            break;

            case SDLK_DOWN:
            velocityY -= PLAYER_VELOCITY;
            break;

            case SDLK_LEFT:
            velocityX += PLAYER_VELOCITY;
            break;

            case SDLK_RIGHT:
            velocityX -= PLAYER_VELOCITY;
            break;
        }
    }
}

bool initialize_game()
{
    bool isSuccessful = true;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        printf("Video failed to load... SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        isSuccessful = false;
    } else {
        globalWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Robo Kill", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(globalWindow == NULL){
            printf("Window failed to be created... SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            isSuccessful = false;
        } else {
            globalRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(globalWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
            if(globalRenderer == NULL){
                printf("Renderer failed to be created... SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                isSuccessful = false;
            } else {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(globalRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                int imageFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
                if(!(IMG_Init(imageFlags) &imageFlags)){
                    printf("SDL_image failed to load... SDL_image error: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
                    isSuccessful = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isSuccessful;
}

bool load_game()
{
    bool isSuccessful = true;

    playerOneTexture = load_texture("images/player1.png");
    if(playerOneTexture == NULL){
        printf("player1.png failed to load...");
        isSuccessful = false;
    }
    return isSuccessful;
}

void close_game()
{
    SDL_DestroyTexture(playerOneTexture);
    playerOneTexture = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(globalRenderer);
    globalRenderer = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyWindow(globalWindow);
    globalWindow = NULL;

    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}

SDL_Texture* load_texture(std::string path)
{
    SDL_Texture* finalTexture = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());

    if(loadedSurface == NULL){
        printf("Image %s failed to load... SDL_image error: %s\n", path.c_str(), IMG_GetError());
    } else {
        finalTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(globalRenderer, loadedSurface);
        if(finalTexture == NULL){
            printf("Failed to create texture from surface...\n");
        }
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
    }
    return finalTexture;
}

bool check_collision(SDL_Rect a, SDL_Rect b)
{
    int leftA, leftB;
    int rightA, rightB;
    int topA, topB;
    int bottomA, bottomB;

    leftA = a.x;
    rightA = a.x + a.w;
    topA = a.y;
    bottomA = a.y + a.h;

    leftB = b.x;
    rightB = b.x + b.w;
    topB = b.y;
    bottomB = b.y + b.h;

    if(bottomA <= topB){
        return false;
    }
    if(topA >= bottomB){
        return false;
    }
    if(rightA <= leftB){
        return false;
    }
    if(leftA >= rightB){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    if(!initialize_game()){
        printf("Failed to initialize...\n");
    } else {
        if(!load_game()) {
            printf("Failed to load game...\n");
        } else {
            bool isRunning = true;

            SDL_Event event;
            Player Player;
            Timer stepTimer;

            SDL_Rect wall;
            wall.x = 90;
            wall.y = 90;
            wall.w = 90;
            wall.h = 90;

            SDL_Rect wall2;
            wall2.x = 256;
            wall2.y = 256;
            wall2.w = 30;
            wall2.h = 40;

            while(isRunning) {
                while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0) {
                    if(event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                        isRunning = false;
                    }
                    Player.handle_player_event(event);
                }
                float timeStep = stepTimer.get_ticks() / 1000.f;

                Player.move_player(timeStep, wall);

                stepTimer.start_timer();

                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(globalRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                SDL_RenderClear(globalRenderer);

                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(globalRenderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
                SDL_RenderDrawRect(globalRenderer, &wall);
                SDL_RenderDrawRect(globalRenderer, &wall2);

                Player.render_player(Player.positionX, Player.positionY, playerOneTexture, NULL, 0.0, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);

                SDL_RenderPresent(globalRenderer);
            }
        }
    }
    close_game();
}
```

Basically, I have my `move_player` function check for collisions by calling `check_collision`. Right now, `check_collision` needs two arguments:  the `playerCollider`, and one other object to collide with.

Note that, in the inside of main, I have two wall rects. Right now, I can only collide with one of the rects, and not the other. I need to be able to collide with both. I'm wondering what the best approach would be for detecting multiple different collisions. Say I have 50 walls in my map, I don't want to have to say "collide with wall X" 50 times. I hope that makes sense.

Feel free to suggest any other improvements to the code too. Also, I based this code heavily off of lazyfoo.net tutorials, so credit goes to them for teaching me what I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have implemented your own rectangle collision check routine when you really didn't have to. SDL provides the function [`SDL_IntersectRect()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_IntersectRect) which tests two `SDL_Rect`s for intersection and also returns the intersection rect of A and B.

---

Now lets talk about coding practices a little bit.

It looks like you are an adept of the [single return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement) statement. In the `initialize_game()` function, for instance, it has lead to a lot of juggling and flag checking to ensure the single return. In that case, it only made the code more complex. You should have just done it like so:

```
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    return false;
}

... stuff ...

if(globalWindow == NULL) {
    return false;
}
```

Prefer to return early and avoid deep nesting. It makes logic easier to follow. The single return technique is hardly applicable to modern C++. The [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom covers dynamic resource management inside functions.

---

Other minor things:

- `NULL` is not C++! `NULL` is a C library macro. Modern C++ should use [nullptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).
- Did you code everything up in the same file? If so, it is probably time to move each class to it's own module.
- Give [`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) a try. You might end up liking it `;)`.

Comment: Okay, that sounds good. Is it possible to pass multiple arguments to SDL_IntersectRect() ? Also, to use nullptr, would I just replace all instances of NULL with nullptr? Or is it more complex than that? Still learning pointers here. I will do some digging and hopefully find a solution.

Comment: @JohnBobSmith - `SDL_IntersectRect` takes 3 rects, `a`, `b` and `c`. `c` is filled with the intersection of `a` and `b` if there is any. Check the documentation in the link.

Comment: @JohnBobSmith - Just replacing `NULL` with `nullptr` should work fine. Your compiler will need **C++11 support to be enabled** (this is probably the default on VS, GCC has to be enabled by you). If you get a compilation error after that, then it probably indicates that you had a bogus conversion somewhere, which is one of the problems of `NULL`. That is easy to fix. But shouldn't happen in your program, I'd guess.

Comment: Okay, my problem that I still have is that I'd have to call SDL_IntersectRect for every rectangle in the map. I want to be able to collide with all objects, not just one. I hope that makes sense. Still looking for a solution to this problem... If a code sample would help, let me know and I will pastebin one.

Comment: @JohnBobSmith - You mean that you want to check collision of each object against every other object?

Comment: No, I want to check the collision of the player against every other object.

Comment: OK, well, there is no magic solution there. You will have to iterate every object and test it against the player. There are several *space partitioning* techniques that you can use to accelerate this though. A [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) is one, for instance.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. Topic solved.